# Why would it be difficult to stop the practice of birthright citizenship in the United States?

Tags: united-states, citizenship

I read on https://amp.theguardian.com/us-news/2020/jan/22/trump-travel-ban-visa-social-security-medicare ([mirror](http://archive.is/djhba)):

> The Trump administration has been restricting all forms of immigration, but *the president has been particularly exercised by the issue of birthright citizenship* – anyone born in the US is considered a citizen, under the constitution. *He has railed against the practice and threatened to end it, but scholars and members of his administration have said it’s not so easy to do*.

Why would it be difficult to stop the practice of birthright citizenship in the United States?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not easy because it would require a constitutional amendment.  The courts have repeatedly ruled that one consequence of the 14th amendment is that everyone born in the US is a US citizen unless the parents are diplomats or part of an occupying force.  Because this provision is part of the constitution, the only way to change it is to change the constitution.